# How can I clean out gems in :development, :test during bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

On continuous integration, I have already installed all the gems needed to run tests and compile assets and such.

Now, I want to reuse the installed gems that are cached on startup and then extracted for each job that needs them.

When I get to the final step I'd like to clean out all the test and development gems from the vendor/bundle in the resulting docker image.

`BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=true BUNDLE_CLEAN=true BUNDLE_WITHOUT=development,test bundle install` doesn't seem to do the job I expected it to do.

Is there another way to clean the gems from the `vendor/bundle` directory that belongs in the environment I want to skip for production deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [bundler documentation](https://bundler.io/v1.16/bundle_config.html):

> without (BUNDLE_WITHOUT): A `:`-separated list of groups whose gems bundler should not install.

You separated groups using coma, not colon which is why this did not work. If you use `--without` instead, list would be space separated.